# How to add Ruby Twitter status parameter to update

Tags: ruby, windows, twitter, parameters, tweets

I get an error that says "Missing required parameter: status. Twitter::Error::Forbidden" How do I add the status param to "client.update()" ?

If I replace "update" with "status", my tweet doesn't post and I get an error saying No status found with that ID. My code is below:

```
def post 
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key = "..."
        config.consumer_secret = "..."
        config.access_token = "..."
        config.access_token_secret = "..."
    end
  File.open("tweets.txt") do |line|
    line.each do |item|
      tweets = item
      puts tweets
      client.update("#{tweets}").to_s
      sleep((rand*1800 +900).to_i)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the version of gem you use?

Comment: Ruby 2.1.5 x64 for windows... should I use the 2.1.5 without x64? Or a different version maybe? @Maxim

Comment: or do you mean version of twitter gem? @Maxim

Comment: yes, i was asking about gem version.

Comment: gem is twitter-5.14.0 @Maxim

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open("tweets.txt") do |line|
  line.each_line do |item|
    tweets = item
    puts tweets
    client.update("#{tweets}")
    sleep((rand*1800 +900).to_i)
  end
end
```